# Can I create two nodes with the same ID in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am simulating a clone attack in mobile sensor network, I want to generate at an instant t of the run-time a dynamic node which has the same type as other nodes and the same ID of an already existing random node.

My question: Is it possible to have two nodes in the same network with same IDs?

Answer (score 0):

No, each node has to have a unique ID.

Comment: In clone attack, the attacker capture a node and create a replica with the same ID of the captured node. How can I achieve this in OMNeT++? Can I add a new parameter to each node so that we can have two nodes with the same new parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by ID? Hardware MAC address? Because that's a different thing than module ID (which is indeed unique).